# NetSuite User Login

Tags: netsuite

In Netsuite,we have scenario where

1. User will login via desktop application.
2. On successfull login we need to redirect user to netsuite webapplication.
3. We want to continue user desktop session in netsuite web application also.

**Note : Login will only be done via desktop application.**

Currenlty we are using Netsuite  webservice with passport authentication.Also is it possible to login netsuite without providing account number.

Answer (score 2):

You can use REST to login without providing the account number:

Using the following URL:

https://rest.netsuite.com/rest/roles

..and passing Authorization in the header:

NLAuth nlauth_email=my@email.com, nlauth_signature=mypassword

http://elibeltran.com/webservice-login-without-providing-an-account-number-is-it-possible/

Comment: We tried that approach but rest is not working for us.If we use Rest then it  would be very difficult to manage user session becuase we want to use user desktop session in netsuite web application also.

Comment: I'm just responding to your question on how to login without having the account number. There is no known webservice solution other than REST.

Comment: Using Netsuite Soap api we are now able to login using passport mechanism.Now we are facing issue of session managment as Netsuite's default session timeout is of 20 mins.We want to keep user sesssion live as per requirment.Is there any way to do the same.

Comment: Here is the latest and greatest NetSuite URL for web services. https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2015_1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can also use Netsuite's Single-Sign On (SSO) feature.  You can either use SAML and set up an IdP server or you can use their Inbound Single Sign-on feature which you have to upgrade to (i.e. pay for) but easier to set up.